# Ask Question - Add image window partially offscreen so add button almost gone

Tags: bug, asking-questions, image-upload

Adding an image like the one below in this editor (How's that for recursion?) has the drag-n-drop popup partially off-screen so that the Add button is inaccessible or almost inaccessible. Since the popup is pinned to the lower-right corner, it cannot be scrolled.

I had to enlarge my browser window to get to it for this image.

Needs margins in the enclosing `<div>` maybe?

[image: Add image window partially off screen]

Comment: It's supposed to be positioned in the centre of the viewport. Which browser (name + version) are you using?

Comment: Very old unsupported Chromium-27 on Puppy Linux 5.2.8 (based on Ubuntu 10.04) on old PC with 2.66GHz CPU and only 2GB memory. Thus, cannot upgrade Chrome/Chromium.

Comment: You'll probably be out of luck then for a fix. ~~Isn't Ubuntu pretty light-weight when it comes to system requirements? Perhaps upgrading is possible?~~ I guess the addition of Unity in newer Ubuntu versions cause trouble for your system?

Comment: That could be. Just spun up first droplet on DigitalOcean which is Ubuntu-16 and noticed the low RAM use. Investigating. (now we're off-topic... but thx)

Comment: I try it with every modern browser i had and the pop up is always well centered, this is a very specific case... so personnaly i don't think it's worth fixing it